# How can I print only the c file's name and authority of the c file in Bash shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to print only the name and authority of the c file in Bash. I know how to print the names and permissions of all files with the awk command, but how can I print only the c file?

Comment: Why `ls -l *.c` is not enough ?

Comment: Use the `*.c` wildcard when getting the list of filenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls -la *.c | awk '{print "Permission:" $1 " Filename:"  $9 }'
```

Should work with this.